# Prove for all $x, y \in \Bbb N$ , $x \mid y (y + 1) \cdots (y + (x - 1))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I need your help with the following proof:

Prove for all $x, y \in \Bbb N$

$$x\mid y  (y + 1) \cdots (y + (x - 1)).$$

What I have so far:

Proof with induction over $x$.

Let $y$ be arbitrary but fixed.

IB: $x = 1$, then $1 \mid y$.

IH: let $x$ be arbitrary but fixed with $x \mid y (y + 1)\cdots (y + (x - 1))$.

Now we have to prove $(x + 1)\mid  y  (y + 1) \cdots (y + (x - 1))  (y + x)$.

From the IH we know that $x\mid y  (y + 1)\cdots (y + (x - 1))$ and we can conclude that 
$x \mid y (y + 1) \cdots (y + (x - 1))  (y + x)$.

So far I have come, but how do I continue and prove divisibility by $x + 1$?

Any help or hint would be really appreciated.

All the best!

Comment: It's not easy at all. In contrast,note that $y, y+1, ... y+(x-1)$ are $x$ consecutive numbers, so at least one of them must leave a remainder of $0$ when divided by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

- $x>y$:

Suppose firstly $x>y$, then $x=y+k, k\in \mathbb{N}$. And of course $k\leq x-1.$

- $x<y$:

Suppose $x<y$ then $x=y-k, k\in \mathbb{N}.$ But you have exactly $x$ consecutive number $y, y+1,..., y+x-1.$ By simple logic we have that one of them have to be $a\cdot x$ for some $a\in \mathbb{N}.$

- $x=y$:

Suppose $x=y$, then it's trivial.

**Approach 2:**

I find that second approach very pleasing.

Note that you can rewrite: $$y(y+1)\cdot \dots\ \cdot (y+x-1)=\frac{(y+x-1)!}{(y-1)!}.$$

> And the question is this divisible by $x$?

We can say much more about it:  it's divisible by $x!$. Because:
$$\frac{(y+x-1)!}{(y-1)!x!}=\binom{y+x-1}{x}.$$ And hence it is of course divisible by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Do the induction on $y$. The case $y=1$ is obvious, as
$$
1(1+1)\dotsm(1+x-1)=x!
$$
is obviously divisible by $x$.

Suppose the case $y$; then
$$
\overbrace{(y+1)\dotsm(y+x-1)}^{\text{common factor}}\,(y+x)-
\underbrace{y\,\overbrace{(y+1)\dotsm(y+x-1)}^{\text{common factor}}}_{\text{divisible by $x$}}=
(y+1)\dotsm(y+x-1)(y+x-y)
$$

Comment: You can say even more: $y(y+1)\cdot \dots \cdot (y+x-1)=\frac{(y+x-1)!}{(y-1)!}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but I do not really understand how you conclude the divisibility by x and I also do not understand why you subtract y(y+1) ... (y + x - 1) from the term before?!

Comment: @Jack The difference in the left-hand side is divisible by $x$; the second term is divisible by $x$, so also the first one is.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thank you. One last question: How do you conclude (y + 2) ... (y + x - 1)(y + x - y) as the difference? I know it is a stupid question, but I just cannot see it right now.

Comment: @Jack I better showed the common factors (and fixed a typo).